# QueueDequeue step is a significant bottleneck in Tensorflow code

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery

I've seen a few other questions regarding the dequeueing step causing a bottleneck but I have tried many of those suggestions without any success:

1. I am using multiple threads based on cpu count
2. I have tried with small batches (of 100) and larger batches (of 1000)
3. I have tried switching to the shuffle_batch_join and batch_join

None of these things seem to be helping the overall time. Also the extent to which the Dequeue step is causing a bottleneck in my code seems much worse than what others have experienced. When you look at the timeline all of the other steps practically disappear in comparison. I am wondering if this is partially from using BigQuery and the [BigQueryReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cloud/BigQueryReader) as my source although with other people also experiencing a slowdown I am assuming it isn't the only cause.

[image: Timeline]

I'm not entirely sure how to properly interpret this chart but it doesn't seem like the the problem is being caused by a completely empty queue.
[image: Tensorboard]

Additional info

- Capacity is set to batch size * 10
- min after dequeue is set to batch size * 2 + 1
- enqueue many is set to true

Does anyone have any thoughts on what else I might be able to try to speed things up while still using bigquery as the source of my data?

Comment: QueueDequeue can take a long time if the queue is empty, so it's waiting for data to appear. You could be bottlenecked by IO. You can look at queue fullness stats on tensorboard to see if that's the case

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I've added the chart from Tensorboard. I may be interpreting it incorrectly but it doesn't seem like it is an issue with an empty queue. What is usually needed to correct an empty queue?

Comment: One way to rule out queue emptiness, is to let queue runners run for a bit, and then start the main loop (with the dequeue), and then look at the timeline. Your particular timeline is from a single session.run, so it could be from a call where dequeue happened.